# Unwanted Navbar transparency in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I'am using Bootstrap 4 in React.js project.
I have two elements - navbar and alert implemented from Bootstrap4.
Since I've set position:fixed in both (overrided css) both of them become semi-transparent. I've never used transparency for neither of them and haven't use rgba color codes for them. It just happened by itself ... why and where I should seek ?

Comment: Try to reproduce in a codepen the issue, else it's impossible to guess.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself. Post it here in hope to be helpful for some other newbie :)
So:

1. When you're using Bootstrap4 read documentation carefully ;)
2. When you want fixed top/bottom navbar WITHOUT transparency instead of overriding .navbar class in your's csses by adding position:fixed apply ready-to-use Bootstrap class fixed-top/fixed-bottom/sticky-top applying them to your html/jsx Bootstrap element
3. Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#placement